# Specific problem with \newcommand entries

Tags: cv

I am trying to write my CV. I used one of the templates, which has:

**`Education Entry`**

```
\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
        \colorbox{Cyan}{%
            \parbox{6em}{%
            \hfill\color{Black}#2}} \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}
```

**`Work Entry`**

```
\newcommand{\WorkEntry}[4]{               
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      
        \colorbox{White}{\color{Black}#2} \par  
        \noindent {#3} \par              
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4
        \normalsize \par}
```

By default, the entry for Education looks like:

```
\EducationEntry{Master's degree in Data Science}{2016-2018}{Higher School of Economics, Moscow}
 {GPA 7.71/10.00}
```

I am running into compile errors `Undefined control sequence` for each of my entries. The packages that I am using:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=1.5in,
            right=1.5in,
            top=.6in,
            bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     
\usepackage{graphicx}                    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            
\usepackage{geometry}
    \textheight=700px                    
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
```

I assume that the problem is with defining entries structure but now I am not sure what exactly to do. Also, after I included the `hyperref` package the problem with compiling occurred.

**UPDATE 1**

My entry is equally formatted as the example above.

The error message is:

```
*Undefined control sequence.
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.*
```

Comment: You have not provided an example, nor shown the error message, which  makes it hard to debug . Probably unrelated but remove `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Completing OP's example shows that package is the source of the problem.

Comment: @Teepeemm then must also be an older release as `utf8x` does nothing in a current release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I actually commented out the suggested line and compile went successfully. You can make an answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \usepackage{hyperref} \begin{document} a \end{document}` on Overleaf with TeXLive 2022 is giving an error.

Comment: What control sequence is undefined? Read your log file carefully.  I don't understand why there is so often a desperate question about "undefined control sequence" without giving a complete error message, what control sequence is undefined. Knuth thought out the message format well, but the vast majority of users did not understand it.

Comment: @wipet a common problem is the texstudio editor which shows  one-line summary of errors rather than the full log, for undefined commands it completely destroys the message just showing the final context line and not which command is undefined. Every few years I try to report it but nothing happens. I don't use that editor myself https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know about it. When I mentioned "vast majority of users" then I included in this the TeXstudio programmers too. Moreover, they called their product "TeX studio" but it is only LaTeX oriented software, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` solved an issue.